# Telerik UI for WPF applying theme. resources not found

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, themes

I followed NoXaml+**Copy the XAML files in a dedicated folder in your application** approach in the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-setting-a-theme-overview).

My project throws `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` "Cannot find MediumBrush. the resource name is case sensitive" right after the `InitializeComponent();` line. The included xaml resource files really does not have MediumBrush key.

When I add `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MediumBrush" Color="Black" />` manually, it throws LowBrush, LayoutControlSplitter_Foreground, and so on.

I referenced dlls as below;

- Telerik.Windows.Controls
- Telerik.Windwos.Controls.Data
- Telerik.Windwos.Controls.DataVisualization
- Telerik.Windwos.Controls.Input
- Telerik.Windwos.Controls.Navigation
- Telerik.Windwos.Data

And, I added xaml Themes;

- System.Windows.xaml
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.xaml
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml
- Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml

Of course I registered xaml resources app App.xaml file.

The thrown resource keys are not appeared on above xaml resource files. Where are these resources actually?

Note: Telerik UI for WPF version 2017.2.503.45 on .Net 4.5 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I used `Background={StaticResource MediumBrush}` in MainWindow.xaml which was not defined.

To fix this, define own SolidColorBrush resource named `x:Key="MediumBrush"` or use `{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=MediumBrush}`

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add a reference to an actual theme DLL, for example **Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black.dll**, that contains the XAML resources and then merge the needed XAML files in your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office_Black;component/Themes/Telerik.Windows.Controls.Data.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: There are two approaches in the document. I'm using http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-setting-a-theme-overview#copy-the-xaml-files-in-a-dedicated-folder-in-your-application while you said http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/styling-and-appearance/styling-apperance-setting-a-theme-overview#reference-the-theme-dll

Comment: The doc described "Copy the XAML files in a dedicated folder in your application" approach does not require to add Theme dll. App.xaml code is different also. Mine is referencing local path (not ";component")